# FireFox keeps asking, "What should Firefox do with this file?" What's the about:config setting in need to change to autodownload?

Tags: python, firefox, mozilla, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to auto download documents with Firefox via Selenium and Python. I've made some attempts at stopping the automatically generated box but Firefox keeps asking, "What should Firefox do with this file?". What's the about:config setting I need to change or add to the Firefox profile so that I don't get this prompt box? My existing code is below:

""

autodlprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

autodlprofile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)

#autodlproflie.set_preference("browser.download.alwaysOpenInSystemViewerContextMenuItem", False)

autodlprofile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r"C:\Users\X\Desktop\Automate the Boring Stuff\taxbills")

autodlprofile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")

autodlprofile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/octet-stream")

autodlprofile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.showOpenOptionForPdfJS", False)

""

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is tested and works as expected (I tested it with firefox version 88.0.1, geckodriver 0.30.0 and Python 3.8.10.
Important Note: be careful if you will use very recent Firefox versions (> 90), I think there might be isssues with the automation of download features).

```
import SeleniumLibrary
from selenium import webdriver
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
def create_profile(self)
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir","**provide_download_dir_here**")
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", 
    "application/zip,application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, 
    multipart/x-zip,image/jpeg,application/xml,application/pdf,text/plain,text/csv, 
    */*")
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
    "application/zip,application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, 
    multipart/x-zip,image/jpeg,application/xml,application/pdf,text/plain,text/csv, 
    */*")
    fp.update_preferences()
    return fp.path
# Add the following code where you open the browser
ff = self.create_profile()   
BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary").open_browser("https://your_url","F    irefox",ff_profile_dir=ff)
```